# Como almacenar datos de formulario en .txt desde formulario? Python - Flask (servidor-web)

Tags: python, flask

Tengo un pequeño servidor web local utilizando python y flask, en un formulario de mi proyecto debo llenarlo y cada vez que se envíe se debe almacenar en un archivo **.txt** con los datos obtenidos del formulario.

Lo que he logrado hacer es obtener esos datos del formulario y almacenarlos en el **.txt** pero al llenarlo nuevamente se sobrescriben los datos.
Cómo podría hacer que se cree una nueva línea con los datos obtenidos del formulario y no reemplazar lo que ya se tenia?

Este es mi código en un archivo llamado: **servidor.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=".")

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
data = request.form
with open('resultado.txt', 'w') as archivo:
    archivo.write(str(data))
print(data)
return render_template('index.html')
```

print(data) muestra esto:

```
  > flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'servidor.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
ImmutableMultiDict([])
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Aug/2021 22:48:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Aug/2021 22:48:17] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 
304 -
ImmutableMultiDict([('name', 'ewerwe'), ('lastname', 'gdfgd'), 
('norobot', 'on'), ('language', 'css')])        
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Aug/2021 22:48:24] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Aug/2021 22:48:24] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 
304 -
```

En mi archivo **.txt** se almacenan los datos obtenidos en el formulario de esta forma:
ImmutableMultiDict([('name', 'aadf'), ('lastname', 'sdfsfsdf'), ('norobot', 'on'), ('language', 'java')])

Este es mi formulario con algunos campos:

```
<body>

   <form method="POST" action="/">
      <label for="name">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      <br>
      <label for="lastname">Apellido</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
      <br>
      <label for="norobot">No soy un robot</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="norobot" id="norobot">
      <br>
      <hr>
      <label for="language">Lenguaje Favorito</label>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="language" id="html" value="html">
      <label for="html">html</label>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="language" id="css" value="css">
      <label for="css">css</label>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="language" id="java" value="java">
      <label for="java">java</label>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

Comment: y que campos tiene tu formulario?, como es la variable `data`?

Comment: ya he actualizado mi pregunta con el formulario.

Comment: te podré ayudar, peroooo....., podrías hacer un `print(data)`?

Comment: actualizado con print(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar datos en modalidad `'a'` de append al trabajar con 'open file'.

```py
with open("sample.txt", "a") as file_object:
    # Append 'hello' at the end of file
    file_object.write("hello")
```

ver fuente del ejemplo: [[ir](https://thispointer.com/how-to-append-text-or-lines-to-a-file-in-python/)]

Para trabajar en local no hay problema, pero al ponerlo en un servicio en la nube el servidor no te va a dejar escribir archivos por seguridad y eficiencia o por lo menos google cloud,con el que he probado, no me deja.

Comment: Si sabias que si el archivo no existe, esto dará un error? Por otra parte  por que escribes `hello` si lo que se pide es escribir los datos del formulario?